# Displaying information about clicked feature in popup in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, features, popup, properties, propertyname

I'm new to OL. I want to display certain information about a point in a pop-up window. Points are drawn from coordinates:

```
       var pointsStation = [     //координаты остановок
    {   id:111, name:'Красноярск АВ', time: "10:45",
        cords:[92.905977,56.03295]
```

These are bus stops, and by clicking on the icon of this stop, the bus arrival time should pop up (time: "10:45").

What should I update and add here to display the time in popup window?

```
function copyCord(vP, startP, endP) {
    var res = [];
    var j = 0;
    for (var i = startP; i < endP; i++) {
        res[j] = ol.proj.transform(vP[i], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
        j++;
    }
    return res;
}

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
var feature;
feature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: '#6A5ACD', weight: 1}),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: '#6A5ACD', width: 4})
    })
);
    vectorSource.addFeature(feature);

var pointsStation = [     //координаты остановок
    {   id:111, name:'Красноярск АВ', time: "10:45",
        cords:[92.905977,56.03295]
  
 function addMarkerStations() {    //стиль иконок
    for (var j = 0; j < pointsStation.length; j++) 
        {
        var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform(pointsStation[j].cords, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
            name: pointsStation[j].name,
            id: 'station-' + pointsStation[j].id
        });
        var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Icon({
            scale: 0.045,
            opacity: 0.75,
            src: "https://znachek.pro/uploads/posts/2023-03/thumbs/1679660159_znachek-pro-p-znak-ostanovka-png-25.png"
            
        })
        
        });
        iconFeature.setStyle([iconStyle]);
        iconFeatures.push(iconFeature);
    }
    iconSource = new ol.source.Vector({features: iconFeatures});
}


function addLabelStations() {     // стиль названий
    for (var j = 0; j < pointsStation.length; j++) {
        var labelFeature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform(pointsStation[j].cords, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
            name: pointsStation[j].name,
            id: 'station-' + pointsStation[j].id
        });

        var labelStyle = new ol.style.Style({
            text: new ol.style.Text({
                font: '12px Arial',
                text: pointsStation[j].name,
                
                overflow: true,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: '#000'
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: '#000',
                    width: 1
                }),
                textBaseline: 'bottom',
                textAlign: 'left',
                rotation: 0,
                offsetY: -8
            })
        });
        labelFeature.setStyle([labelStyle]);
        labelFeatures.push(labelFeature);
    }
    labelSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: labelFeatures
    });
}

addMarkerStations();
addLabelStations();
/******************************************************* */

var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
    /**
     радиус, после которого близконаходящиеся объекты
     объединяются и считаются
     */
    distance: 40,
    /**
     * Координаты самих объектов
     */
    source: labelSource,
});

var styleCache = {};
/**
 * Создаем слой Кластер
 * и задаем для него стили
 */
var clusters = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: clusterSource,
    style: function (feature, resolution) {
        var size = feature.get('features').length;
        var style = styleCache[size];
        if (!style && size >= 2) {
            style = [new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius: 20,
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: '#fff'
                    }),
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: '#3399CC',
                        // color: '#ff0000'
                    })
                }),
                text: new ol.style.Text({
                    // text: listSt,
                    text: size.toString(),
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: '#fff'
                    }),
                    scale: 2
                })
            })];
            styleCache[size] = style;
        }
        return style;
    }
});
/********************************************* */

 // showMarketStation();

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM(),
            name: 'Map'
        }),
        new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: vectorSource,
            name: 'Road'
        }),
        new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: iconSource,
            name: 'imgStations'
        }),
        new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: labelSource,
            name: 'labelStations'
        }),
        clusters
    ],
    overlays: [],
    // renderer: 'canvas',
    view: new ol.View({
        // Координаты центра
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([92.905977, 56.03295]),
        zoom: 12,
        minZoom: 5,
        maxZoom: 25
    })
});
var container = document.getElementById("popup");
var content = document.getElementById("popup-content");
var popupCloser = document.getElementById("popup-closer");

var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
element: container,
autoPan: true

});






map.on('click',function(e){     // всплывающее окно
var pixel = map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent);
console.log(pixel);

map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel,function(feature){
var coodinate = e.coordinate;

content.innerHTML = "<p>Станция:" + coodinate + "</p>";
overlay.setPosition(coodinate); 
map.addOverlay(overlay);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With statement `name: pointsStation[j].name` you are assigning feature property `name`. You can to the same for `time` property:

```
var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform(pointsStation[j].cords, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
  name: pointsStation[j].name,
  time: pointsStation[j].time,
  id: 'station-' + pointsStation[j].id
});
```

You can retrieve these properties later with `feature.get('name')` and `feature.get('time')`.

Popup creation code could then look like something like this:

```
map.on('click', function(e) {
  var pixel = map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent);
  map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature) {
    var coodinate = e.coordinate;
    var name = feature.get('name');
    var time = feature.get('time');
    content.innerHTML =
      '<p>Name:' + name + '</p>' +
      '<p>Time:' + time + '</p>' +
      '<p>Coordinate:' + coodinate + '</p>';
    overlay.setPosition(coodinate); 
    map.addOverlay(overlay);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Can I contact you in the future if I have any questions?